# Loop through UITableView with sections

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, pointers, integer

I am trying to combine two example codes on the Apple developers site called *2_SimpleSectionedTableView*, and *TableSearch*.
Essentially I want to be able to use a `UISearchBar` to filter through a table of timezones with sections. The code below crashes my app saying

> Incompatible integer to pointer conversion.

What does this mean and how do i fix it?

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText
{
/*
 Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.
 */

[self.filteredListContent removeAllObjects]; // First clear the filtered array.

/*
 Search the main list for products whose type matches the scope (if selected) and whose name matches searchText; add items that match to the filtered array.
 */

for (NSInteger i=0; i<[self.regions count]; i++)
{
    Region *region = [self.regions objectAtIndex:i];
    for (NSInteger j=0; j<[region.timeZoneWrappers count]; j++) {
        {
            NSComparisonResult result = [[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:i length:j] ].textLabel.text compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
            if (result == NSOrderedSame)
            {
                [self.filteredListContent addObject:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:i length:j]]];
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Note: no need to repeat the `Region *region = [self.regions objectAtIndex:j];` line

Comment: Also, are you trying to compare the strings to determine if searchText is exactly the same as the beginning of the localeName?

Comment: yeah so in the example, if you search for 'ip' then iPhone, ipod etc would show as a result. However if you searched for 'iphones' the results would return nil.

Comment: k, NSString has a method `hasPrefix` which may be more succinct for you: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: thanks, but at the moment I cannot get s specific cell. Im looking for something similar to the cellforrowatindexpath method. Is there something similar that i can use in this block of code?

Answer (score 0):

The crash happens here:

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:i length:j]
```

This method expects a pointer (not an integer!) as the first parameter:

```
+ (id)indexPathWithIndexes:(NSUInteger *)indexes length:(NSUInteger)length;
```

You should use the table view specific method instead:

```
+ (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRow:(NSInteger)row inSection:(NSInteger)section;
```